# Euler numbers and Tangent function.

Tags: analysis, summation, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

> Q.How can I describe the relationship between Euler numbers and tangent function in a "one" sum sign?

Here's how I dealt with Euler numbers and tangent functions:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n E_{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}=\dfrac{1}{\cos x}
\end{align}

So I multiplied both sides with $\sin x$. I did Mertens Multiplication:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k E_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!}x^{2i+1}
\end{align}

It follows that

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^i \dfrac{(-1)^k E_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k} \cdot\dfrac{(-1)^{i-k}}{(2i-2k+1)!}x^{2i-2k+1}\right)
\end{align}

If we rearrenge

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^i  \dfrac{E_{2k}}{(2k)!(2(i-k)+1)!}\right)x^{2i+1}(-1)^i
\end{align}

I think my question is now more explicit. But I want to restate my question. Here in the sum we have two sum sign, so How can I delete one which can be deletable?

Edit:
\begin{align}
\sum_{0\leq k\leq 2i}^\infty  \dfrac{(x^{2i+1}(-1)^i)E_{2k}}{(2k)!(2(i-k)+1)!}
\end{align}

Second Edit:

\begin{align}
\sum_{0\leq k\leq 2i}^\infty  {2i+1 \choose 2k}\dfrac{(x^{2i+1}(-1)^i)E_{2k}}{(2i+1)!}
\end{align}

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. The power series $$\tan x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1}$$ uses Bernoulli numbers, not Euler numbers.

Comment: I know but in this summation Euler numbers work

Comment: I calculated few terms and it went fine.

Comment: I don't argue your deductions. I just don't understand what you aim to get. The series for the tangent function (without any inner summation) is given in my first comment. Yes, you have an alternative representation for its coefficients as certain linear combinations of Euler numbers. But what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I'm askıng for how can I simplify this formula? Because you can see we have "i" and "k" in this formula, are there any way to reduce these two to just "k" or "i" ?

Comment: I'm saying it the 3rd time: after such a reduction, the *only* result you can get is the formula in my 1st comment. The power series (for any function) is *unique*.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It might also be just a matter of convention as there exist slightly different definitions of *[Euler numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html)*.

R. P. Stanley for instance defines even and odd *Euler numbers* in the 2nd edition of *[Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. I](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-i)* via generating functions as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 0}E_{2n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}&=\frac{1}{\cos x}\tag{1.53}\\
\sum_{n\geq 0}E_{2n+1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}&=\tan x\tag{1.54}\\
\end{align*}
from which we easily conclude
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 0}E_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=\frac{1}{\cos x}+\tan x}
\end{align*}
This formula is stated in *Proposition 1.6.1*. He also notes after the example 1.4.2 that: Originally, $(-1)^nE_{2n}$ was called an *Euler number*.